# C# and Reflection don't work twice in a row

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I've a problem and I can't figured it out how to solve it.

I've a class for fetching data from a Database, in this class I've a method for a simple **select *** this method is called

```
List<T> All<T>(string tableName)
```

and you have to specify which resource you want to fetch, for example

```
All<User>("users")
```

And, aside from the classic SQL Reader and SQL Command, the core of the method is this

```
public override List<T> All<T>(string resource) 
    {
        List<T> result = new List<T>();
        using (MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            try
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM " + resource + " WHERE 1=1";
                using (MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
                {
                    lock (locker)
                    {
                        MySqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                T model = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                                Dictionary<string, object> _properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                                {
                                    string property = reader.GetName(i);
                                    object value = reader.GetValue(i);
                                    _properties.Add(property, value);
                                }
                                var type = model.GetType();
                                var method = type.GetMethod("SetProperties");
                                var invoked = method.Invoke(model, new object[] { _properties });

                                result.Add(model);
                            }
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Program.eventLogger.Add(new Event(EventType.Error, "SQL Data Providers", "Exception catched on All", ex));
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Basically, based on the Type from the method header, the method will try to create an new instance of the specific type, later for each field from the query, it will fills all the attributes of the class on a temporaneous list. Once it's done it will try to call the method "SetProperties" which basically set every attributes of the class using reflection.

This is the core of SetProperties, equal for each entity:

```
    public virtual bool SetProperties(Dictionary<string,object> properties)
    {
        if(this.ValidateData(properties))
        {
            FillNullableAttributes(properties);
            // Iterate trough every key : value pairs in properties
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in properties)
            {
                if (this.data.Contains(kvp.Key))
                {
                    var property = this.GetType().GetProperty(kvp.Key);
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(kvp.Key);
                    // Set the current fetched key with the given value if !null
                    if (kvp.Value != null)
                    {
                        Type fetchedType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType;
                        object safeConversion = (kvp.Value == null || kvp.Value == DBNull.Value) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(kvp.Value, fetchedType);
                        if (propertyInfo.CanWrite)
                        {
                            propertyInfo.SetValue(this, safeConversion, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In conclusion the result, which is a list, will be returned and the specific Entity will have its own BindingList filled. The binding list, for each entity is described as follow:

```
public static BindingList<Seller> items = new BindingList<Seller>();
```

This code works fine, even if there's a lot of space for improvements I know, but if I called it twice like this:

```
User.items = new BindingList<User>(provider.All<User>("users"));
User.items = new BindingList<User>(provider.All<User>("users"));
```

The second list will be filled by empty entities, the counting of the will be correct but they will be empties... and that shouldn't occurs.

The only thing that I figured it out, from the debugging, is that on the second call

```
var invoked = method.Invoke(model, new object[] { _properties });
```

invoked is set to false.

Comment: So, I know this doesn't answer your question, but why not force the models to implement an interface that contains the `SetProperties` method.  It will be a lot more performant.

Comment: Is the reader re-initialized properly so the call to Read() returns data?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd yes, it's closed and open properly for every SQL Call

Comment: You should disclose a *complete* piece of code.

Comment: Is it the `All<User>` that returns a set of empty models, or is it the `new BindingList<User>` that ends up being full of empty models?

Comment: @CodingGorilla Exactly what I wanted to suggest. Aside from performance, it's primarily a matter of readability and there's no reason why `All<T>` should use reflection. Then it will be easier to debug and figure out the issue.

Comment: @CodingGorilla the problem is that result.Add in All<T> receive an empty Model

Comment: So you say `invoked` ends up being false, that is the return value from your `SetProperties` method, so what does that mean?

Comment: @CodingGorilla it means that the invoke didn't actually invoke anything

Comment: No it doesn't read the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx  `Return Value ...
An object containing the return value of the invoked method, or null in the case of a constructor.`  **Your** method is returning false, why, probably because it encountered an error?

Comment: @CodingGorilla Yea but why is returning false only the second time and not the first one? Also I'm gonna debug that

Comment: @CodingGorilla JEEZ i figured it out. The ValidateParameters is the cause. How can I give to you the accepted answer now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of:

```
var invoked = method.Invoke(model, new object[] { _properties });
```

Is the return value from your `SetProperties` method, *not* whether the method was invoked as your question indicates.  Your `SetProperties` method is telling you that it was unable to do its work, debug that and you will find your answer.

Comment: BTW - I still suggest you implement an interface. :)

Comment: I know, this was not part of my code in the project I had to take over and this is the result